# How Can I Subtract The Value Of A Object By The Value Of Another Object?

Tags: javascript, object

I'm new to coding so I might not have the best code but I have a object called computer and another called player. I want to subtract the value of the computers health by the value of the players attack power. Here is the code I currently have:

```
var player = {
  health: 100,
  attackPower: function () {
    return Math.round(Math.random() * 10)
  },
  turnId: 0
}

var computer = {
  health: 1,
  attackPower: function () {
    return Math.round(Math.random() * 10)
  },
  turnId: 1
}

function playerAttack() {
  computer.forEach(e => e.health -= player.attackPower)
  console.log(computer.health)
}

function computerChoice() {
  ranNum = Math.round(Math.random() * 2)

  if (ranNum == 1) {
    return player.health - computer.attackPower
  } else if (ranNum == 2) {
    return computer.health + computer.attackPower
  }
}
```

Any help will be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: what issue your are facing?

Comment: Every time I run the code it doesn't subtract the computer health by the players attack power, which is what I want.